# split last section of a string in c#

Tags: c#, string, split

i have a kind of input in my program witch users type a link like "http://www.example.com/dd/sa/...../sample.png"
and i looking for a code to give me the last section of the link (sample.png)

> More accurate:
>
> **user type this in a textbox** : "http://www.example.com/dd/sa/...../sample.png"
>
> **and i receive this** : string a = "sample.png"

in other hand i want know all elements after last "/" in my program. i think we can use split() or trim() but i don't know how!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`Path.GetFileName(String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method

```
var filename = Path.GetFileName("http://www.example.com/dd/sa/whatever/sample.png");
```

or

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.example.com/dd/sa/whatever/sample.png");
var name = uri.Segments[uri.Segments.Length - 1];
```